# How to update Microsoft Teams manifest of the bot for all users?

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to allow the users that are already talking to the bot upload files (attaching the files to the bot).

I uploaded a manifest with "supportsFiles": true through "Upload Custom App".

But this only affects my conversation with the bot, the other users' manifest doesn't look like its updated because they can't see the attachment button.

Is there a way to update the bot's manifest for all the users in the organization?

This is not a published application, the users talk to the bot through the link from the registered bot in Azure Portal.

Any help is appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Bots which are accessed via link won't update as there is no metadata associated with it. You need to create [App Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview) for you Microsoft Teams.

Once you've created your app there are [three options for distributing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/overview) it.

1. Upload your app directly.
2. Publish your app to your organization's app catalog
3. Publish your app through AppSource

Please go through the options provided in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/overview) and let us know if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks alot, I didn't know that there was no metadata associated and I thought that it was the same bot/manifest. Just confirmed that if it's an administrator that registers the app, it works for all the user.